# PigServer leaving job jars on local filesystem

Tags: java, apache-pig

I'm using Pig in an java application. Currently I have a thread that runs a pig query every 15mins. After every run I'm left with the MR Job Jar in my temp folder, in my case /tmp.

They way the code is structured is 1 instance of a PigServer is created on start up. Then on a loop I re-register a query with different partitions and execute the query via the openIterator call. The PigServer is not shutdown until the thread is shutdown.

So my question becomes is there a call I need to preform to clean up the jars? or do I need to shutdown the PigServer for every execution? or should I just clean up the FS myself after the query is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you do need to create and destroy your PigServer object after each use to clean up the pig* directories in the tmp space. However this doesn't appear to clean up the Job jars. So I did have to institute my own cleanup function to handle this.

Comment: What you mean by that? Just trying to leave an answer encase anyone else comes across the same issue.

Comment: You are just writing "It appears YOU do need"... :) Like you have 2 instances of yourself. :) Sorry, if it offended you, bro.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. Was just confused.